# How to change blob for one specific repo in Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, blob, azure-storage, databricks

I have a specific environment cluster in DataBricks. There I have many different repos used by other people. Each Repo loads data from one specific "x" blob container created for this environment. Question is how to match one of these repos with another already created blob named "y"?

This is how it works now - blob "x" used by:

- repo 1
- repo 2
- repo 3

How I want it to work - blob "x" used by:

- repo 1
- repo 3

blob "y" used by:

- repo 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduce following procedure in my environment with two repo's

blob x -> blob_container

blob y -> blob_container2

repo 1
[image]

repo 2
[image]

reading file from blob_container
[image]

loading it to repo2 to blob_container2
[image]